# How to output array with keys to my html file from promise function using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, promise

I have some firebase database with tags "bookName" and "author".
How can i render array from function "getBook"?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import firebase from '../firebase/firebase.js';

export default class booksComponent extends Component{

getBook(){
  const newArray = [];
  console.log("i am working")
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.settings({
     timestampsInSnapshots: true
  });
  db.collection("LibraryDB").where("user", "==",  
     firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            newArray.push(doc.data());
        });
        return(newArray);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
};
render(){
  return(
    <div>
         <button/>
    <div>
     ------
     {this.getBook()}
     </div>
 </div>
  )};
};
```

In console output looks like:

```
[{author: "Ernest Hemingway", bookName: "Fiesta", user: 
"eZGZbRijz6RF8FkMhngiE9FAnf63"},
{author: "J. R. R. Tolkien", bookName: "LOTR", user: 
"eZGZbRijz6RF8FkMhngiE9FAnf63"},
{author: "Ernest Hemingway", bookName: "The Old Man and Sea", user: 
"eZGZbRijz6RF8FkMhngiE9FAnf63"}]
```

But how put these information to render()?

Comment: Why do not you save your base data in a state and render the state data directly?

Comment: Well what specifically do you mean by render an array? Technically your output is an array, a JSON array but an array nonetheless. Can you clarify?

Comment: @basic I need to create in render  table with colums "author" and "bookName" using keys from JSON array

Comment: You should now get a table you should just press the button to load the data.  You can also call it in componentDidMount as stated before to make sure that it fetches initially

Comment: I also added it so that you can use the user as the key to prevent that React error.

Comment: @Moosecouture - book.user is not unique, don't use it as a key. Check the sample data.

Comment: @Moosecouture Thank you for help. But then i use your code i get this error: "Error getting documents:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at BooksComponent.js:30 " How can i fix it?

Comment: I know why.  Let me fix.

Comment: I updated.  It had to do with the scope of 'this' because you are not using arrow functions

Comment: @Moosecouture Thank you! It finally work))

Comment: Can you mark it as best answer, please?

Comment: @Moosecouture I clicked to "check mark" =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import firebase from '../firebase/firebase.js';

export default class BooksComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      books: []
    }
    this.getBook = this.getBook.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBook();
  }
  getBook(){
    const newArray = [];
    const selfThis = this;
    console.log("i am working")
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.settings({
      timestampsInSnapshots: true
    });
    db.collection("LibraryDB").where("user", "==",  
      firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
              newArray.push(doc.data());
          });
          selfThis.setState({
            books: newArray
          })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
  };
  render(){

    return(
      <div>

        <div>
            <button onClick={this.getBook}/>
        <div>
        ------
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Book Name</th>
          </tr>
            {this.state.books.map(book => <tr key={book.user}>
              <td>{book.author}</td>
              <td>{book.bookName}</td>
            </tr>)}
          </table>
        </div>

  )};
};
```

Comment: bind onClick on the new button the getBook method and not the it's result ;) (and help the OP with giving the button a visible text :D )

Comment: Actually, I just accidentally called it.  I can just not call it and pass it.

Answer (score 1):

You could start fetching your data in `componentWillMount` method and save data in component field (e.g. `books`). Then you could check this field in `render` and based on its value return some stub or array.

```
{
  this.books && this.books.length
  ? <your-array books="this.books"></your-array>
  : <span>No books</span>
}
```

You should set `books` field via `setState` (the simplest way) to notify component for rendering again.

Answer (score 1):

It works best with state. Declare a state for your component and call setState after you've loaded the data. In the render method, simply say {this.state.book} and react will re-render the component when the state has been updated.

We shouldn't play with async/await here and delay the rendering. Rendering has to be quick and fast and we have to expect that the data hasn't arrive yet when we render the page.

So, for a quick win, :

```
export default class booksComponent extends Component{

state = {
  books: null,   // we start with not having a books, later it's an array of books
}

getBook() {

   // ...
   // instead of return(newArray) inside your method, say:
   this.setState({books: newArray});
}

componentDidMount() {
   if (this.state.books === null) {
      this.getBooks();  // here we start the accessing the db
   }
}

render(){
  return(
    <div>
         <button/>
    <div>
     ------
     {this.state.books && this.state.books.map((book) => {
       return <p key={book.bookName}>{book.bookName} by {book.author}</p>
     })}
     </div>
 </div>
  )};
};
```